# Display SectionList from local json file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a `SectionList` from a json file named `notes.json`. Basically one object in the `notes` json array will correspond to one `SectionList` entry. I already load the json array in `notesData`. However, when i try to use `notesData` as a source for my `SectionList` i get the error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.sections.reduce')`

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SectionList, ListItem, H1 } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { styles } from '~/containers/Notes/styles';

import { notes } from './Notes.json';

const notesData = [];
Object.keys(notes).forEach((key) => {
    notesData.push(notes[key]);
});

class NotesContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <SectionList
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem title={item.RELEASE_NOTE} />}
                    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <Text title={section.RELEASE_VERSION} />}
                    sections={this.notesData}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export { NotesContainer };
export default connect(null, null)(NotesContainer);
```

Here is my Notes.json

```
{
  "notes": [
    {
      "RELEASE_VERSION": "0.1.1",
      "RELEASE_DATE": "01 Mar 2018",
      "RELEASE_NOTE": [
        "General bug fixes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "RELEASE_VERSION": "0.1.0",
      "RELEASE_DATE": "01 Feb 2018",
      "RELEASE_NOTE": [
        "Initial Launch"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you want to iterate this json ?

Comment: @SangramBadi basically create a list based on this json file. One entry of the list corresponds to one object within the `notes` json array

Comment: explain clearlly in your question

Comment: @bennygenel see the edit. Then ask yourself if it is a duplicate

Comment: first of all I don't think `notesData` have any items in it. try logging it and see if it does have any data. Secondly,  I think `sections={this.notesData}` should be `sections={notesData}`.

Comment: and third. I think you should be the one asking himself/herself if its a duplicate. Mine was just a suggestion. That is why it says _Possible duplicate..._ If its not a duplicate system will regulate and fix my error. I was trying to lead you a way to fix your problem. Be more open to suggestion.

Comment: @bennygenel notesData does have items. I just printed out `notesData[0].RELEASE_NOTE`

Comment: @stud91 I think you should change definition `const notesData = [];` to `let notesData = [];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data structure for `SectionList` is not correct, it should have a [`data` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#section) with the array of data you want to render in that section.  Below there is an example for the data you have.

> **section**
>
> An object that identifies the data to be rendered for a given section.
>
> Properties:
>
> `data` array
>
> The data for rendering items in this section. Array of
>   objects, much like FlatList's data prop.

**Example**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.notesData = Object.keys(notes).map((key) => {
      return { data: notes[key].RELEASE_NOTE, version: notes[key].RELEASE_VERSION }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <Text>{section.version}</Text>}
            sections={this.notesData}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it does view the list but raises a warning: `missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor`

Comment: check the [documentation for `SectionList`'s keyExtractor prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#keyextractor)

Answer (score -1):

You can do lists which based on your json data with ListView component;

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
   this.listNotes = this.listNotes.bind(this);

   this.state = {
      notesData: this.ds.cloneWithRows({}),
   };
}

componentWillMount() {
   this.setState({ notesData: this.ds.cloneWithRows([notes]) });
} 

renderState() {
  return (
    <View>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.notesData}
        enableEmptySections
        renderRow={this.listNotes}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

listNotes(rowData) {
   return (
      <View>
         {rowData.map((item, key) => (
             <View key={key}>
               ...
             </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
 }

 render() {
    <ScrollView>
      {this.renderState()}
    </ScrollView>
 }
```